# google maps v3 not returning places for some queries

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, google-api, google-places

I am implementing place / local search using gmaps v3 javascript library. The idea is to get listings / places by query and location text.
I am using  PlacesService object and search function to get list of places.

```
// code
 service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
//search
 var req = { keyword: qry, location: location, radius: 1000 };
 service.search(req, function (results, status) {
       // do something
 });
```

The issue is this does not return any results for some "select" keywords which are commercial I guess, like I get results when I search for food, pizza, car near chicago etc. but when I search bmw, audi dealer, hyundai etc. near chicago, no results. If I enter the same query in maps.google.com, I get a bunch of listings with ads. 
Ideally, I would want the exact same data from api, but don't know why no results show up for some queries.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `types` parameter manually? It could be that the default value for this does not include all types.

Comment: actually I intentionally ommitted types param as I want keyword based result of all relevant listings, like "car" should have car dealers, car washes, car auto parts etc. just like how user would expect.

Comment: I meant just for debugging, to see if ommitting the parameter does really search for *all* types or only for a specific subset of it.